# Two JComboBoxes user can't choose same value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I've got two `JComboBox`. First one has model with elements "one", "two", "three" and second has model with elements "three", "four". And when user choose element "three" in first `JComboBox`, he can't choose element "three" in second one `JComboBox`. And in reverse - when user choose element "three" in second one `JComboBox`, he can't choose same element in first one CB. How can i do this in Java ?

Thank you for answers. 
One more question. When i dynamically create ComboBoxes (when someone clicked the button - in button actionListener), and every new ComboBox has same model - same list of elements. How can i check this case ? Same like Blip said ?

Comment: It would be easier and more user friendly to check for duplicates and remove them when building the DefaultListModels of the JComboBoxes.

Comment: I have added more information in my answer to accommodate for you new additional question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you could add `ItemListener` to the 2 `JComboBox`. If the user selects the object `"three"` in any of the `JComboBox` then the object `"three"` could be removed from the other `JComboBox`'s model. And if the user deselects the object `"three"` in one `JComboBox` then the object `"three"` can be added to the model of the other `JComboBox`.

You could implement in the following way:

1. Lets have have the two `JComboBox` stored in variables `box1` and `box2` which could be implemented as :

   ```
   JComboBox<String> box1 = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
   JComboBox<String> box2 = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"three", "four"});
   ```
2. Now add `itemListener` to both these `JComboBox` and pass it to a method say `boxItemSelected`:

   ```
   box1.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

       itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
           boxItemSelected(e);
       }
   });
   box2.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

       itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
           boxItemSelected(e);
       }
   });
   ```
3. Now to implement the `boxItemSelected(e)`

   ```
   void boxItemSelected(ItemEvent e){

       //Check the item selected/deselected is "three" else do nothing.
       if (e.getItem().equals("three")){ 

       //Find the box on which this action was not performed to change its model.
           JComboBox<String> oppositeBox;
           if(e.getSource().equals(box1)){
               oppositeBox = box2;
           }else{
               oppositeBox = box1;
           }

       //Check the item is selected or deselected to remove or add "three" to item list.
           if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
               oppositeBox.removeItem("three");
           }else{
               oppositeBox.addItem("three");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Addition Information**

Here if you have more than 1 items that are overlapping and can be selected only in one `JComboBox`, a slight modification of the method `boxItemSelected` could be take care of your problem as Illustrate below:

Change the line in the above code from:

```
if (e.getItem().equals("three"))
```

to

```
if (e.getItem().equals("three") || e.getItem().equals("<new item>") || ....)
```

And change

```
oppositeBox.removeItem("three");
oppositeBox.addItem("three");
```

to

```
oppositeBox.removeItem(e.getItem());
oppositeBox.addItem(e.getItem());
```

Here under any circumstance the user cannot select the same items in both the `JComboBox`. And all these happen behind the scene without the knowledge of the user using the user-interface.

> When i dynamically create ComboBoxes (when someone clicked the button
>   - in button actionListener), and every new ComboBox has same model - same list of elements. How can i check this case ? Same like Blip said
>   ?

In response to the above I am considering that all the items in all the `JComboBox` same and are stored in a `List` variable, and if 1 item is selected in any one of the `JComboBox` then that item cannot be selected in rest of the `JComboBox`. If my assumption is correct, then I suggest you do the following:

1. Create a `List<JComboBox<?>>` say `boxes` and initialise it as below:

   ```
   List<JComboBox<?>> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. In your `JButton` (the button that dynamically `JComboBox`) variable's `ActionListener` implementation create a variable say `items` as an instance of `List` to store the items of the `JComboBox` and add the items

   ```
   List<String> items = new Vector<>();
   items.add("One");
   items.add("Two");
   ......
   ```
3. Now remove the items from from the `items` variable that are selected in other `JComboBox` that are dynamically generated:

   ```
      Iterator<JComboBox<?>> iterator = boxes.iterator();
      while(iterator.hasNext()){
          JComboBox<?> existing = iterator.next();
          items.remove(existing.getSelectedItem());
      }
   ```
4. Now after initialisation of the `JComboBox` instance say `box` set the Model of the `box` to the previously initialised and trimmed `List` variable `items`

   ```
   box.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(items));
   ```
5. now add the `JComboBox` variable `box` to the `List` variable `boxes`:

   ```
   boxes.add(box);
   ```
6. Also in this above mentioned `ActionListener` implementation add the `ItemListener` to `box`, the newly instantiated variable of `JComboBox` and pass it to the method `boxItemSelected`:

   ```
   box.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

       itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
           boxItemSelected(e);
       }
   });
   ```
7. Now the implementation of the `boxItemSelected` has to be changed to accommodate the changes:

   ```
   void boxItemSelected(ItemEvent e){

       //Create an iterator to iterate over the boxes 
       Iterator<JComboBox<?>> iterator = boxes.iterator();

       while(iterator.hasNext()){

           //Get the current instance of comboBox from the list
           JComboBox<?> current = iterator.next();

           //If the box in which the select or de-select 
           //event has occurred is the current comboBox then do nothing.
           if(e.getSource().equals(current)(
               continue;
           }

           //If the event is select then remove the Item from the 
           //current comboBox else add the Item to the current comboBox.
           if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
               current.removeItem(e.getItem());
           }else{
               current.addItem(e.getItem());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @JacobRutka I have added more information in my answer to accommodate for you new additional question.

Comment: In your code - when i run application and change selected value in box2 for "four" then i will have in box1 two values "three"... Because i set after run in box2 selected value equals "three".

Comment: @JacobRutka I thought of this problem just after I had signed out an hour ago. Could you tell me how you are initialising the `JComboBox` or how are you adding the `ComboBox` model in your program? So that I can give a specific solution to this problem.

Comment: @JacobRutka I have corrected my answer for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

So this is definitely possible. The best way I think would be to check the selected index of both boxes and then perform your logic based on the results of that index value. In the example below you can see that demonstrated. What is happening is there is an ActionListener on ComboBox1 and 2. If the values match, I used index but you can also get the string value to make sure they don't match up.

```
public class SOF extends JFrame {
private JPanel mainPanel, comboPanel;
private JComboBox jcb1, jcb2;

public SOF()
{
    super("Combo Box Example");
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(configureCombo());
    add(mainPanel);
    setSize(200,200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


    jcb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           //You can replace this with, jcb2.getSelectedItem if you don't know the indexes or if they will be random. 
           if((jcb1.getSelectedIndex() == 2) && (jcb2.getSelectedIndex() == 0))
           {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot select 3 in both field.");
               jcb1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
               jcb2.setSelectedIndex(-1);
           }
            //ANOTHER OPTION
           If((jcb1.getSelectedValue().equals("three") && (jcb2.getSelectedValue().equals("three")
           {
            LOGIC
           }
       }
    });

    jcb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           //You can replace this with, jcb2.getSelectedItem if you don't know the indexes or if they will be random. 
           if((jcb2.getSelectedIndex() == 0) && (jcb1.getSelectedIndex() == 2))
           {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot select 3 in both field.");
               jcb1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
               jcb2.setSelectedIndex(-1);
           }
       }
    });


}

private JPanel configureCombo()
{
    String[] cb1List = {"one", "two", "three"};
    String[] cb2List = {"three", "four"};
    comboPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    jcb1 = new JComboBox(cb1List);
    jcb2 = new JComboBox(cb2List);
    comboPanel.add(jcb1);
    comboPanel.add(jcb2);
    return comboPanel;
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SOF s = new SOF();
}

}
```

On either one if matching boxes are selected an error message will pop up and deselect both comboboxes.

Comment: I think, i can't use getSelectedIndex() method because when someone change (in future) elements order or elements names everything will blow up... am i right ?

Comment: That's true you could also use getSelectedValue()  which would allow to you compare the string value contained in the element. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could futz with the combobox's model, but easier would be to just check the selected values when the user asks the program to accept the values, perhaps in the ActionListener of a JButton, and then if two of the same values have been selected, deselect them and warn the user with a JOptionPane. Alternatively, you could have code in listeners (either Actionlistener or ItemListener) added to both JComboBox's that check the other combobox's selected value to make sure that they are not the same, and if so, warn the user and deselect the erroneous selection.